# DateTimeZone error: Unknown or bad timezone

Tags: php

I am trying to run this script:

```
<?php
$d = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'));
$time = $d->format('H:i');

echo $time;
?>
```

but I got this error:

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTimeZone::__construct() [<a href='function.DateTimeZone---construct'>function.DateTimeZone---construct</a>]: Unknown or bad timezone (Asia/Kolkata)`

Though it works well for `Asia/Dacca` for example. What could be the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: `print_r( DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers() );` does it return `Asia/Kolkata` ?

Answer (score 4):

And welcome to StackOverflow! If you haven't already make some time to read the FAQ.

I tried your example and it worked for me with PHP 5.3.1 and "Olson" Timezone Database Version **2009.18** .

You should do a `phpinfo()` and see what time zone DB version you have and if it's older update it. You can see in [this list](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.asia.php) that the most recent version, 2011.1, has Asia/Kolkata.

Answer (score 4):

I've got same problem when try to run webserver in CHROOT jail. In this case chrooted dir can not contain Linux timezone files. If it's your case and you have access to webserver files simple copy all files to chroot jail:

For CentOS it's

```
cp -R /usr/share/zoneinfo/ /MY_CHROOT_DIR/usr/share/
```

Comment: Brother its 7 years old but I just fell into this exact issue with php 7.4, `timezone_identifiers_list()` was returning empty and I couldn't figure it out, phpinfo was exactly the same as a working stage, then I read this and found a jailed user (not jailed in stage!) and bingo bango. Have my upvote, wish it could be more. My thanks to you!

Answer (score 3):

Try this for fun.

```
$timezones = array('Europe/London', 'Mars/Phobos', 'Asia/Kolkata');

foreach ($timezones as $tz) {
    try {
        $mars = new DateTimeZone($tz);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by renaming /etc/localtime.

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old database with a list of timezones, upgrade it via pecl. The latest version of the timezone database can be installed via [PECL](https://pecl.php.net/get/timezonedb) -`timezonedb`.

```
pecl upgrade timezonedb OR pecl install timezonedb
```

Answer (score -1):

PHP timezone database has been updated in version 5.3. Try installing that and try again